# C# using access modifiers to bottleneck access to Simulation

Tags: c#

I want to prevent that someone interacts with a simulation in a way that he shouldn't. The only allowed way is to implement a method of the Interface "IInteraction" and add this interaction to a list. The SimulationController then goes through this list and executes the method at an appropriate time.
So every class related to the simulation has to be accessible only by IInteraction (regardless from where IInteraction gets implemented).

I tried to make the simulation class internal, as this would restrict anyone from accessing it. But the Interaction needs a reference to the simulation to be able to manipulate it. A reference to it is only possible inside the assembly of the Simulation, which makes this approach useless, because that way the implementation of IInterface can't be made from a public scope.

Comment: Are you looking for an architectural answer? What you have to do to implement a plugin like system?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight IInteraction shouldn't be hidden. If you are referencing to the last sentence: I tried to use internal, without realisin, that the implementation of IInteraction would also have to be inside the simulation, and as you said that is pointless.

Comment: @Butterkekskrumel I guess you should explain what's wrong with having `IInteraction` public, because to me it looks like you have it all figured out correctly. By the way, you can expose internals to a selected list of outside DLLs. Look up "internalsvisibleto attribute".

Comment: @mjwills please say what parts you don't understand. I tried to be as precise as possible.

Comment: @Icepickle I'm not experienced with C# nor setting up a nice architecture, so if a redesign of the architecture is necessary, I would be happy to learn about it.

Comment: @Butterkekskrumel Then, I would suggest you lay out your current setup, where are your interfaces located, what is needed for people to create a specific `IInteraction` implementation, what's the current setup of loading those interactions? We are generally clueless about how your application looks, so it doesn't make it easier to suggest how you should change your implementation

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thats exactly my point, IInteraction should be public. But with the Simulation beeing internal, an implementation of IInteraction can't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `IInteraction` should be public. But with the `Simulation` being internal, an implementation of `IInteraction` can't access it.

The trick to this is to publish an interface `ISimulation`, letting `IInteraction` program to its interface. An `internal` implementation of `ISimulation` would remain hidden from `IInteraction` implementations.

```
public interface ISimulation {
    void SetSomethingUp();
    void DoSomething();
}
public interface IInteraction {
    void Process(ISimulator simulator);
}
...
internal class Simulator : ISimulator {
    public void SetSomethingUp() {
        ...
    }
    public void DoSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```